# Math and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and still learning. I am having one heck of a time trying to figure out how to create this program. I have tried multiple ways and spent about 4 hours now trying to get this to work and it still wont outprint what I need it to. I need a 10x5 array with the first 25 digits being the index variable squared and the last 25 digits being the index times 3. What it is outprinting is 5 numbers over and over 10 times. But it's like it is not reading the "next index variable". I get: `0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, etc..` Here is what I have so far(please don't rate down, I'm trying hard to learn this!):

```
public class snhu4 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    double alpha[][] = new double [10][5];

    for (int col=0; col<=9;col++) {
      for (int row=0; row<=4;row++) {
        alpha[col][row]= Math.pow(row,2);

        System.out.println(alpha[col][row]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you using an array? if you must use an array, what do you mean by "the first 25 numbers"?

Comment: For the first 25 numbers, I am referencing the ten numbers in row 0, ten numbers in row 1, and 5 numbers in row 2.

Comment: You should start by trying to understand what your program currently does. You're setting the values of each row (the inner loop) to the same values. You said it yourself, you don't keep track of any index. And btw, the outer loop loops over rows, and the inner one loops over columns, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double[][] alpha = new double[10][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            int index = (5 * i + j);
            if (index < 25) {
                alpha[i][j] = (index * index);
                System.out.println("index(" + index + ")^2 =" + alpha[i][j]);
            } else {
                alpha[i][j] = (3 * index);
                System.out.println("3*index(" + index + ") = " + alpha[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're right @Lopina, that's what I was trying to do with the index

Answer (score 1):

You need an `index` variable initialized to zero outside of the loops and incremented (`index++`) inside the inner loop. Then you can perform the calculations on the `index` (0-49) rather than the `row` variable, which keeps looping 0-4. You'll also need a conditional (`if` statement) that performs one calculation if index is < 25 and a different calculation if index >= 25.

Comment: alternatively the index is also `col*5+row` in this case

Comment: Yes, though that would introduce duplication of the number (concept) 5, which could be extracted into a variable to remove the duplication. The OP could also use a ternary operator (?:) instead of an if. Might not be so readable though.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a generalised version, compared to the accepted answer. It will give the same output, though.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    double alpha[][] = new double [10][5];

    int index = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < alpha.length; row++) 
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < alpha[row].length; col++) 
        {
            if (index < 25)
                alpha[row][col] = Math.pow(index, 2);
            else
                alpha[row][col] = index * 3;

            index++;

            System.out.println(alpha[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println("" + '\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always using the `row` variable to calculate the assignment value, I think you should combine the values of `row` and `col` (or maybe use an index as aetheria says), something like this:

```
    double alpha[][] = new double[10][5];
    for (int col = 0; col <= 9; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row <= 4; row++) {
            if (col < 5) //if column >= 5 that means that you just passed the 25 index
                alpha[col][row] = Math.pow(row + (col*row), 2);
            else {
                alpha[col][row] = Math.pow(row + (col*row), 3);
            }
        }
    }
```

I couldn't test it (my eclipse is totally crushed) but I think that will give you the idea (probably you will need to play with the "row + (col*row)" part, when one of the variables is 0 it will not fit your needs). Hope this helps, regards.

Comment: I would like to know why the vote down, maybe the answer is not 100% correct but I'm giving an approach about the source of the problem and how can be solved, please tell me so I can take it into account for the next time